# Code not working in google chrome but works fine with Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies, mozilla

i am working on this fiddle with cookies. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PzKUh/). but it works fine with Mozilla for the first time. when i delete all the cookies but when ever i reopen the page it goes directly to the second div which has to be displayed after the button click from the first div. as well as the second div must be shown and first div must be hidden when refreshed. and even this does not work for chrome in any ways. any idea or suggestions to improve. thanks in advance. 
  here is my code:

```
       $('#sbut1').click(function() { 
       $('.cont1').show();
     $('#log1').hide();
        $.cookie('shown', true);

        });

     $(function() {
      if ($.cookie('shown')) {
         $('#sbut1').click()
       }
        });
```

Comment: Firstly, bind your click handler _inside_ of the `$(function(){})` (ready callback), because chances are that the bind is being called before DOM has been loaded that far down. After that, test in incognito/private mode, cookies will be automatically removed when you end the anonymous session, that way you don't have to clear & double check all the cookies time and time again. PS: your fiddle works fine in chrome for me... but that might be down to the `onload` option selected on the left-hand side of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:*

there was a slight syntax error in my answer (forgot closing parentheses for IIFE). Anyway, [**here's an updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PzKUh/3/), and (for completeness) here's the code. I've optimized it some more, but it's basically the same thing:

```
$(function()
{
    (function(sbut1)
    {
        (function(log1, cont1)
        {
            sbut1.on('click',function()
            {
                cont1.show();
                log1.hide();
                $.cookie('shown', true);
                $(this).off('click');
            });
        }($('#log1'), $('.cont1')));
        if ($.cookie('shown'))
        {
            sbut1.trigger('click');
        }
    }($('#sbut1')));
});
```

There's a couple of things that might seem irrelevant (like binding and unbinding the event listeners), but the comments in the fiddle explain why I'm doing this. The main reason is to clean up any references to the DOM, in order for them to be flagged for garbage collection.
Again, this code works just fine for me in both FF and chrome

In response to my last comment, same thing, only vanillaJS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function l()
{
    var cookie = (function(trueUndef)
    {
        var clean = (localStorage || document.cookie);
        return function(name, val)
        {
            if (val === trueUndef)
            {
                if (clean === localStorage)
                {
                    return clean.getItem(name);
                }
                val = clean.split(name + '=')[1];
                return val ? val.match(/^[^;]+/)[0] : trueUndef;
            }
            if (clean === localStorage)
            {
                return clean.setItem(name, val);
            }
            return !!(clean = name + '=' + val);
        };
    }()),
    sbut1 = document.getElementById('sbut1');
    sbut1.addEventListener('click', (function clickHandler(log1, cont1)
    {
        return function(i)
        {
            log1.style.display = 'none';
            for(i=0;i<cont1.length;i++)
            {
                cont1[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
            cookie('foo', true);
            sbut1.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
        };
    }(document.getElementById('log1'), document.getElementsByClassName('cont1'))), false);
    if (cookie('foo') === 'true')
    {
        sbut1.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }
    window.removeEventListener('load',l, false);
}, false);
```

---

I've had a look at your fiddle, and changed the code to this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#sbut1').click(function()
    { 
        $('.cont1').show();
        $('#log1').hide();
        $.cookie('shown', true);
    });
    if ($.cookie('shown'))
    {
        $('#sbut1').click()
    }
});
```

Which works like a charm, for me (with option *no wrap - in head*) [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/PzKUh/2/)

Just a side-note, you're using *a lot* of DOM selectors, which is calling functions all over the place, and queries the DOM way too much. Your code could be a lot more efficient if you assigned a reference to these DOM nodes somewhere:

```
$(function()
{
    (function(sbut1, log1, cont1)
    {
        sbut1 = sbut1 || $('#sbut1');//safety-net
        log1 = log1 || $('#log1');
        cont1 = cont1 || $('.cont1');
        sbut1.click(function()
        {
            cont1.show();
            log1.hide();
            $.cookie('shown', true);
        });
        if ($.cookie('shown'))
        {
            sbut1.click();
        }
    }($('#sbut1'), $('#log1'), $('.cont1')));
});
```

The IIFE is optional, of course, but it wraps the DOM references in a scope, so they're only available to those parts of your script that actually *need* them.
There's a lot of ways to improve on this code, still, but excess DOM queries are easy to avoid, so I thought I'd suggest you taking care of those.

Comment: :thank you for the response. but the problem still persist when i write this function in $document.onload() and i have even tried with $document.ready(). can you please do make changes in the fiddle .

Comment: @HkM: check your console, `$document.onload` and `$document.ready` probably both throw syntax-errors. It's supposed to be `$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});` or just `$(function(){/*code here*/});` There's a link to an updated fiddle just below the first snippet, that one works just fine

Comment: @HkM: Please do check your console (ctrl+shift+j) for errors, meanwhile, here's a tried 'n tested [vanillaJS implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/) of the very same functionality, just for fun, and to show that JS isn't as clucnky and hacky as once it was

Comment: the fiddle works perfect in my chrome browser. but i dont know where the problem lies in when i incorporate with my project code and see that in chrome. there is no problem with mozilla: any guess wi this happens?

Comment: @HkM: did you check your console, and did you clear chrome's cache? to double-check: make the changes to your script, and open chrome in incognito-mode, that way it won't use any cached files

Comment: @HkM: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I'm currious to know what it was that was actually causing the issue

Comment: you are welcome. but even i am working on it. the idea which you gave in the previous comment even does not seemeto work. but the same code works fine for safari as Mozilla. the issue is only with chrome. i am now trying to link the external js file internally and check for chrome. but even in the fiddle the linking is only external. any way. let me try.

Comment: @HkM: Check your chrome settings on X-domain setings, I'll also post a vanillaJS alternative version that works on chrome, and -if needs must- I can edit it to support IE<9, too. IE8 will work, probably IE7, too

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest on responding to my concern. I will check the steps which you said and let u know at once.

Comment: i the mean time. i will check with this vanilla.js example http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/ fiddle. which you posted yesterday.

Comment: :Superb, the vanilla.js code works fine on the chrome. but the issue is that it directly logs in to the second div when i restart my browser and empty my cookies without showing the login div. and this same happens with Mozilla also.

Comment: @HkM, that's because the VanillaJS is using thre `localStorage` object when available.

Comment: @HkM: [here's a vanillaJS fiddle that supports older browsers and older IE's, too](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/2/), and [here's a fiddle that works on cookies only](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/3/), not `localStorage`, so you can test it more easily (clearing cookies in browser)

Comment: in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/3/. it logs in to the second div. but when i refresh it comes back to the first div.

Comment: the thing i am looking for is when the first page is opened for the first time it has to display the login div . and when we click the submit button it has to open the second div by hiding the first. then whenever i press refresh in the second div it must show only the second div and not the first one.

Comment: @HkM: That's got something to do with `document.cookie` and the way jsfiddle works (iFrames) --> the one document !== the next... perhaps try it on your own page. There's also a typo: `cookie('foo', true)` is used to set the cookie, whereas I'm checking `cookie('foo') === 'true'`, so best change the first statement to `cookie('foo', 'true')`

Comment: @HkM: PS: I think I've done more than enough to get you on your way here, so I'd greatly appreciate an upvote for my efforts, too. My emplyer pays me for this stuff, so asking for a free click isn't too much I'd say

Comment: thank you very much for the efforts taken by you. Hats off for your Work. Please continue to do this. As i am a beginner i asked more questions to you,  i am sorry about that. here afterwards Let me think of the solution before asking a question.

Comment: @HkM: What version of jQ are you using? if it's jQ2.x, you'll have to add `$ = jQuery;` to your script, or wrap the entire thing in a `(function($){/*code here*/}(jQuery));` IIFE, because `$` doesn't reference the jQ object anymore

Comment: final post in SO,made the changes in the code but i works the same way as it was before and also the log1div page loads only for few seconds and navigates to cont1 div . here is my code: cookie('foo', 'true');
            sbut1.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
        };
    }(document.getElementById('log1'), document.getElementsByClassName('cont1'))), false);
    if (cookie('foo') === 'true')
    {
        sbut1.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }window.removeEventListener('load',l, false);
}, false);

Comment: @HkM: what _"version"_ of my snippet are you using? check for `var clean = document.cookie`, instead of `var clean = (localStorage || document.cookie)`

Comment: Sorry there was a Typo. its http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/2/ snippet which i am using it.

Comment: @HkM: [try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/6/), the code you're using doesn't set a cookie in chrome/ff, but uses the `localStorage` object. The fiddle doesn't work because of the iFrames (as I mentioned), but try using it in your project

Comment: in my project http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/6/ works like the previous one which you have given: http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/3/

Comment: i am very grateful to you. i used session storage instead of local storage. it worked like charm. Hats off for your idea. here is my updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7Sc6B/12/

Comment: but i dono whats wrong with my acc now. it says 'this site no longer acceps questions". i dono what to do

Comment: @HkM: It's not the site, it'll probably be your account: [you've asked the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335266/jquery-code-does-not-work-in-chrome), so the admins probably restricted your account for a while

Comment: @HkM: So you can't vote answers up, either? That's weird, though... perhaps worth a question on meta?

Comment: i could n get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @HkM: Well, when I asked if you wanted to +1 my answer, you said you got a message saying _"this site no longer accepts questions"_. So I presumed you can't vote on answers anymore, but I see you _can_ still vote on comments. That's weird IMO, so I wanted to make sure I understood your issues with the site correctly, so if you can't +1 any answer anymore, I would post a question about this on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Eilas Van Ootegem: yes i can give +1 for the answer, even though my acc is blocked to post questions. if possible post a question and find out the solution.

Comment: @Hkm: Why didn't you +1 my answer, then? (sorry for banging on about this, but I'd like to know)